# WinRM not working with internal ip address of GCP from vpn source

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vpn, winrm, windows-firewall

On connecting my on-prem network with GCP VPC using GCP VPN, from the on-prem network can i access the virtual machine in GCP VPC using the internal IP address. I have configured GCP windows VM to enable WinRM and created firewall rules in GCP and made sure WinRM service is on with appropriate ports open.

If I use external IP I can run the command to get output from a machine which is not on VPN.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName <ExternalIP> -ScriptBlock {Get-UICulture} -Credential $credential
```

If I run the same command from a machine which is on VPN network with internal ip, it gives me error

> Connecting to remote server 10.xxx.x.xx failed with the following
> error message : The WinRM client cannot process the request. If the
> authentication scheme is different from Kerberos, or if the client
> computer is not joined to a domain, then HTTPS transport must be used
> or the destination machine must be added to the TrustedHosts
> configuration setting. Use winrm.cmd to configure TrustedHosts. Note
> that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated.
> You can get more information about that by running the following
> command: winrm help config. For more information, see the
> about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
>
> CategoryInfo : OpenError: (10.xxx.x.xx:String) [],
> PSRemotingTransportException FullyQualifiedErrorId :
> ServerNotTrusted,PSSessionStateBroken

Not sure as all the firewall rules are fine and there is no rule which says that I can't use internal ip address for winrm commands.

Comment: This looks like a client side trust issue from this part of the error message **WinRM client cannot process the request**. Try this command: `Set-Item wsman:\localhost\client\trustedhosts <target machine>`

Comment: Are you using Active Directory for authentication? Edit your question with more details.

Comment: Security: make double sure that the WinRM ports are not open to the Internet. Lock them down with VPC firewall rules.

Comment: @  user1258028
Could you please share if the command that John recommended works for you? Additionally, it would be very useful if you can edit your question with the authentication method you are using.